# Adding contact to the phone book using code?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

In WP7.5(Mango), is it possible to add a contact to the phone book through code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no API to save the contact directly from the code as it deals with user data.
But you can save the contact from your application by using the `SaveContactTask` with user intervention.

you can use the following code

```
SaveContactTask saveContactTask = new SaveContactTask();
saveContactTask.Company = "WindowsPhoneGeek";
saveContactTask.FirstName = "John";
saveContactTask.LastName = "Smith";
saveContactTask.HomePhone = "000-125-547";
saveContactTask.HomeAddressCity = "London";
saveContactTask.HomeAddressCountry = "UK";
saveContactTask.HomeAddressStreet = "123 Bake Road";
saveContactTask.HomeAddressZipCode = "W11 2BQ";     
saveContactTask.JobTitle = "Software Developer";

saveContactTask.Show();
```

[You can refer this blog for the more information.](http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/8-How-to-use-SaveContactTask-in-Windows-Phone-Mango)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. You should use the new API,

```
       using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
       SaveContactTask newContact = new SaveContactTask();
        newContact.FirstName = "x";
        newContact.LastName = "Y";
        newContact.MobilePhone = "0123456789";
        newContact.Show();
```

Also refer this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202995(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: In my view that is not direct api, It needs user intervention to save data.

Comment: what i mean in my point of view, This Api is not meant for saving the new contact directly to the Contacts, rather it needs user intervention to save to contacts.

Comment: This is done in favor of the security of the user data in Windows Phone. :)

Comment: Have u tried this code ever before? The Contact will be shown in the contact list. Then, you can save it or discard it. And yes u r right it needs user intervention to save the new contact.

Comment: I tried :) , I was highlighting your last sentence that is "it needs user intervention to save the new contact".

Comment: All the tasks that are Listed under that Microsoft.Phone.Tasks API needs user intervention to get completed.